# Angular Caching remvoal

Tags: angularjs, caching

My aim was to remove the http request from the cache storage.

I tried with the below code , but still it seems that the removal of my needed item from the cache was not working. Below is my code.

My Initial Call:

```
$http({method:"get",                                       
url:"http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld"})    
.then(function(response) {
debugger;
 $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
 });
```

Again I will make the call by removing the item from the cache

```
$scope.CallAgain = function()
{
debugger;
var $httpCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
$httpCache.remove("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld");
$http({ method:"get" ,   
url:"http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld"})
.then(function(response) {

  $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
 });
};
```

Though I removed the item from the cache, but still I could see that my webservice was not hitting.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Make sure that two consecutive requests to the same URL always call the web service? If so, why don't you add some headers to the request to deactivate the cache?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. My exact aim was if I make three api calls then my cache will have three records. In that I need to remove the second api call alone. So for that I am trying to remove an API call from the cache entry but in the above example code it was not working

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get it... Do you want to remove the second call from the cache to ensure that it really goes to the server and not take a cached value from a previous call?

Comment: $http responses are not cached by default. I don't see the `cache` property being set on the config object. For more information, see [AngularJS $http service API reference - Caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching).